# Script for massive update does not finish

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-update

I have written a simple script to massively download and install Windows Updates onto fresh OS installations. For most of them the script well accomplish the installation. Last but not the least, the most recent cumulative update is downloaded and installation started. But the installation never ends (ie the progress bar does not complete) and the script remains hanged up. How to force the finalization?

Edit: the same task, from the Windows Update GUI, works

Here there is my script:

```
# elevated script execution with admin privileges
$currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$testadmin = $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
if ($testadmin -eq $false) {
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
}

# setting script execution policy
$ErrorActionPreference= 'SilentlyContinue'
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
$ErrorActionPreference= 'Inquire'

$ErrorActionPreference= 'Stop'
try {
    Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
} catch {
    Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Confirm:$False -Force
    Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
}
$ErrorActionPreference= 'Inquire'

# list of available updates
# Get-Windowsupdate

# install the updates
Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -Confirm:$False
```

Comment: My guess is that one of the updates wants a reboot of the system and is waiting for that to happen. You can either add switch `-IgnoreReboot` or `-AutoReboot` to the Install-WindowsUpdate cmdlet.

Comment: Not sure at all... usually PowerShell notified me reboots needed in the past runs. Not in the last occurrences